How to configure VS Code interactive window workingdirectory to a script in a subfolder?
My project is organized as follow:
├── data                   
│   ├── processed          # The final data sets for modeling
│   └── raw                # The original data files.
├── src                    
│    └── preprocessing.py  # Script for data treatment
     └── utils.py          # Support functions

inside preprocessing.py I have:
import pandas as pd
from utils import ETL

df_ini = pd.read_csv("data/raw/data_raw.csv", sep=";", index_col=0)

this works when I execute the script using Python ( CWD configured to be ${workspaceFolder})
But when I execute it in Interactive window,I get:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
If I change the CWD to fileDirname, I will have a problem with the "data/raw/data_raw.csv" link.
Is it possible to keep using ${workspaceFolder} for the project and have Python find utils.py next to the executed script?

pass the directory to process as a parameter to the script, and if parameter set cwd inside the script

You could try to add .env file under the workspace to solve this issue.
PYTHONPATH=PATH/TO/utils

Then add the following codes to your settings.json:
"python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env"

Some relevant supplementary information:



Run option
.env setting
launch.json setting




Run Python file in terminal
no
no


Run in interactive Window
yes
no


Debug via F5
yes
yes


"Debug Python File" (*)
yes
no




Hello,
Thank you for your help,
This doesn't work,
However, adding "jupyter.notebookFileRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/.env" corrects the import of utils but generates the problem of loading data
I created a file in the workspaceFolder called .env in which I put : PYTHONPATH='src/'
